# how to make a tkinter button click itself?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-button

I'm trying to make a clicker game for my friend. I just want to know how to make a button that when clicked, clicks another button. Here is some of the code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import time
root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x600')
score = 2000000
clicker_counter = 0

def counter():
    global score
    score += 1
    points_label.config(text=score)

def autoclicker(args):
    global clicker_counter
    if args == 1:
        pass

def clickerpurchase():
    global clicker_counter
    global score
    if score >= 1000:
        score -= 1000
        clicker_counter += 1
        points_label.config(text=score)
        clicker_label['text'] += str(clicker_counter)
        clicker_label.config(text='purchase clicker(1k): ' + str(clicker_counter))

clicker_button = Button(root, text='purchase', command=lambda:[clickerpurchase, autoclicker(1)])
clicker_button.grid(row=0, column=3)

clicker_label = Label(root, text='purchase clicker(1k): ')
clicker_label.grid(row=0, column=2)

points_label = Label(root, text='0')
points_label.grid(row=0, column=1)

points_button = Button(root, text='click me', command=counter)
points_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

points_label.config(text=score)
root.mainloop()
```

The `clicker_button` is the main concern. The `clickerpurchase()` function is in charge of updating the `score` and `clicker_counter`. The button is also tied to `autoclicker(args)`. I want the `clicker_button` to click the `points_button` every once in a while. I was thinking of putting the auto clicking code in the `autoclicker(args)` function, but I don't know the code for it.

EDIT:
I made a 'while' loop in my `counter()` function and added `args` to it. I gave `points_button` an arg of 1 and `clicker_button` an arg of 2. My code now looks like this:

```
def counter(args):
    global score
    if args == 1:
        score += 1
        points_label.config(text=score)
    if args == 2:
        while args == 2:
            time.sleep(1)
            points_button.invoke()

points_button = Button(root, text='click me', command=counter(1))
points_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

clicker_button = Button(root, text='purchase', command=lambda:[clickerpurchase, counter(2)])
clicker_button.grid(row=0, column=3)
```

Whenever I click the `clicker_button` the `points_button` gets clicked, but the program crashes. I completely discarded the `autoclicker(args)` function.

Comment: Why exactly do you want the button to be clicked? You can just call the associated function `counter()` every once in a while as you desire.

Comment: Also, what significance does value of `args` hold?

Comment: @AST the args value does not do anything. I was just looking for a way to solve the problem.

Comment: Read the documentation. The  button has an `invoke` method.

Comment: @AST instead of clicking manually to get the score I want the program to click for me every once in a while. Note that the score is supposed to equal to zero. I set it high for testing purposes

Comment: @BryanOakley could you please link me to it? I can't find it

Comment: @MaZe `invoke()`  takes no parameter. So just  use `clicker_button.invoke()` if you want to invoke the clicker_button

Comment: `import tkinter; print(help(tk.Button.invoke))`

Comment: You do realize that you needed to use `()` with `command=lambda:[clickerpurchase(), autoclicker(1)]` right?

Comment: @coolcloud I figured that out already. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as your function is concerned, you could try something like this

```py
def autoclicker(args):
    global clicker_counter
    if args == 1:
        time_interval=1000 #change it as you like
        points_button.invoke()
        root.after(time_interval,lambda:autoclicker(1))
```

I have used the `root.after()` method and this will invoke your `points_button` every `time_interval` milliseconds you specify.

Also, by what I have understood your aim is (please feel free to correct me on this), you don't really need a button to increase the score in the first place, you can just replace the `points_button.invoke()` in the code with `counter()` and it should give the same result. Even if you plan to have multiple of these, you can maybe pass on a different arguments to `clickerpurchase()`, `counter()`, `autoclicker(args)` to have different scores for each item.

**EDIT** (after question edit)

`time.sleep()` in an infinite loop will not work as the entire program will wait for that to be complete before it can execute any other thing, and so it stops responding and crashes. Try to use the `.after()` method in a similar way as I have mentioned above.

And if you want to work without the `autoclicker()` function as you said in the edit, you can make the following changes

```py
def counter(args):
    global score
    if args==1:
        score += 1
        points_label.config(text=score)
    elif args==2:
        time_interval=1000 #change it as you like
        points_button.invoke()
        root.after(time_interval,lambda:counter(2))

points_button = Button(root, text='click me', command=lambda:counter(1))
```

Comment: Another thing just for your information, I have noticed something which could be a logical issue, if the person clicks the `clicker_button` after they have already clicked it, since you have linked the `counter(2)` to the button, it will increase the frequency of score update and will fail to decrease the score as well, to overcome this, you can remove calling the `counter` function from the purchase button and add some condition in `clickerpurchase` like `counter(2)` is only called `if score==0`.